# Is it possible to use Single File Vue Components in premade html files

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to create a Flask project but I wanted to use Vue as well. I've done some reading about how I can use js files and combine them into my html files and make components like that, but I want to be able to create vue files and use them in my index.html without having to generate an app.html from webpack. I'd like to be able to use a component made in a vue file inside an index.html that I'm already using in flask. Is this possible?

```
webapp
|-- static
  |-- css
  |-- vueComponents
    |--  Hello.vue
  |-- js
  |-- templates
    |-- index.html (not generated by webpack and vue)
```

Comment: "I want to be able to create vue files and use them in my index.html... without... webpack".  Not possible because `.vue` files are only understood by Webpack.

Comment: My only problem with webpack is that it creates an index.html and I'm not able to place the components in other html files that I make. Or is my understanding of how it works incorrecet @Dan

Comment: Typically, Vue is used for SPAs (single-page applications), so that's partially correct, however, those applications can have many routes, which are the equivalent of many pages.  It's much better to use Webpack, and worth the time to learn it.  It's quite easy to get up and running and there are other added benefits.  I would suggest using VSCode or any IDE with folder view if you want a good feel for the folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

Yep. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Direct-lt-script-gt-Include

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="foo"></div>
```

```js
new Vue({
    el: "#foo",
    template: `<span>Hello world!</span>`
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is, but there are some disadvantages using this approach for big projects. You can read more [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html). For a small size project, you can use Vue.component and render using css selectors creating a Vue instance. You can check this [here](https://code.sololearn.com/WSVbt1CIc2Rz/#html)